# Regular expression to find a middle of a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
1,11,cda74944-1c61-4325-8137-83a4ab50cb81-A00123,Bs000000216,20140204185143.811
```

Can you provide me regular expression or java string function to get the sub string:

`cda74944-1c61-4325-8137-83a4ab50cb81-A00123` ?

Comment: is this part always the third one?

Comment: 1) what is regular about the input. 2) What have you tried first?

Answer (score 2):

You split the string:

```
String[] array = String.split(",");
```

This will return an `Array` of `String` like this

```
["1", "11", "cda74944-1c61-4325-8137-83a4ab50cb81-A00123", "Bs000000216", "20140204185143.811"]
```

You can access the part you want in `array[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a string like this, use pattern:

```
/\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}-\w{6}/
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is:

```
[a-f0-9]++(?>-[a-z0-9]++)+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the String

```
String[] allStrings= String.split(",");
then try to get allStrings[2]  //it will give you the desired result  cda74944-1c61-4325-8137-83a4ab50cb81-A00123
```

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

Using length:

```
String s = yourString.subString(0, yourString.length() >>> 1);
```

Using split:

```
String s = yourString.split(",")[2];
```

Alternatively, if you have something representing physical data that is always represented similarly, it might be smarter to wrap it in a class instead.